# andengine: call in updatethread freezes ui thread/animations

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, andengine

I'm trying to build my first project with the andengine. things work fine so far but i have a problem with the threading model. 
As far as I know calculations should be done in the update thread to prevent the ui from freezing. 
So to make sure my calculations really take place in the updatethread I made a mock method with a for-loop to check if the screens freezes and unfortunately it does. so this is my test code:

this is how I initialize the scene:

```
private void init() {
        engine.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
            gamemodel.test();
        }

        @Override
        public void reset() {
        }

    });
```

gamemodel is an object from this class:

```
public class Game {

    public void test() {
       for(int i=0;i<100000000;++i) {
       }
    }

}
```

I also tried to call the test-Method within engine.runOnUpdateThread but it did not work either.

I would except that the animations (animatedsprites) in the scene won't freeze because the test-method is not called in the UI thread. So what is acutally happening here and what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I found out by myself registering an updatehandler just means that the updatehandler is run within the next call of the update-method of the andengine. 
if you want to run a method asynchronously you have to do within an asynctask or something similar.